# What is the new searchdefaulthash in the Firefox profile search metadata?

Tags: privacy

During a recent review of changes to the Firefox profile (I'm version controlling it) there turned out to be a new property `searchdefaulthash` in `search-metadata.json`:

```
"[global]":{
    [...]
    "searchdefault":"Google",
    "searchdefaulthash":"fGiy1O53LgQtereW/4qUSlwFfagTNKGghURIbAFw8wY=",
    "searchdefaultexpir":1442682088627
}
```

It looks like the output of `openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64`, but the input is not simply `Google`:

```
$ printf Google | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64
zncGZ+X5sNj1U2e7eUGWidkMSEUbsz8Hnzqacq4TLeg=
```

**The concern is whether this is something personally identifying which is sent when searching on Google.** I could find literally nothing about `searchdefaulthash` on Google and DuckDuckGo, so I'm a bit stumped how it's created & used.

Update: It [looks like](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?q=searchdefaulthash&redirect=true&case=false&limit=84&offset=0) it has something to do with [making some search engines only visible in some countries](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/462b94db3335), although the reason for that is puzzling.